# django channels group_send not working suddenly

Tags: django, django-channels, consumer

I have recently converted my existing django project to have a react front end. However , im facing the issue whereby the backend of my django-channels is not working. The issue im having is that the group_send method is not working in my case , as such the consumer does not receive the information generated by a signal in my models. Here is my code :

## consumers.py

```
class NotificationConsumer (AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
async def connect (self):
    close_old_connections()
    user = self.scope["user"]
    if not user.is_anonymous:

        await self.accept()
        #connects the user to his/her websocket channel
        group_name = "notifications_{}".format(str(user))
        print(group_name)
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(group_name, self.channel_name)


async def disconnect (self, code):
    close_old_connections()
    user = self.scope["user"]
    if not user.is_anonymous:
        #Notifications
        notifications_group_name = "notifications_{}".format(str(user))
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(notifications_group_name, self.channel_name)

async def user_notification (self, event):
    close_old_connections()
    print('Notification recieved by consumer')
    await self.send_json({
        'event': 'notification',
        'data': {
            'event_type': 'notification',
            'notification_pk': event['notification_pk'],
            'link': event['link'],
            'date_created': event['date_created'],
            'object_preview': event['object_preview'],
        }
    })
    print(event)
```

## Models/signals

```
def ChannelNotification(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
if created:
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    print(channel_layer)
    group_name = "notifications_{}".format(str(instance.target))
    print('inside channel signal')
    print(group_name)

    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        group_name, {
            "type": "user_notification",
            "notification_pk": instance.pk,
            "link": instance.object_url,
            "date_created": instance.time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
            "object_preview": instance.object_preview,
        }
    )
```

Whenever an notification object is created in the database , the signal will be sent to my `ChannelNotification` which receives this information and transmit it to the consumer via group send . It used to work perfectly but im not sure what happened after i converted my project to have react as a frontend.

Comment: It seems like there are issues with indentation, please, correct them.